# NullPointer when call entity Manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I try to write some programme using Java, Hibernate and Spring. I see NullPointerException when I call the SQL query. I tried perhaps every samples of code on the internet, but I don't know how to do this. How can I solve it? This is my sample code. There is my full code of programme: https://github.com/lukasz-chojn/films_database/tree/master/src/main/java/Films

```
    @Controller
    public class DataFromUserController {
        private FilmDaoImpl filmDaoImpl = new FilmDaoImpl();
        private DirectorDaoImpl directorDaoImpl = new DirectorDaoImpl();
        private Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
        private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(locale);

        public FilmDs collectData() {
            //....

            filmDaoImpl.insert(film);
            directorDaoImpl.insert(director);

            return film;
        }

        private String collectTitle() {
            System.out.print("Podaj tytuł filmu: ");
            String tytul = sc.nextLine();
            List<String> existingEntry = filmDaoImpl.existingTitle();
            if (existingEntry.contains(tytul)) {
                System.out.println("Tytuł jest już w bazie. Podaj inny");
                return collectTitle();
            }
                if (tytul.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Tytuł nie może być pusty. Podaj go");
                    return collectTitle();
                }
            return tytul;
        }//......
    }

    @Service
    @Transactional
    public class FilmDaoImpl implements FilmDAO {

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        //......
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<String> existingTitle() {
            List<String> titleInTheDatabase;
    // here is NPE
    return titleInTheDatabase = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT film.tytul FROM FilmDs film").getResultList();
        }

        //....
    }
```

Comment: provide your persistence.xml, I suppose that there is no mapping for entity

Comment: There is no persistence.xml. Everything is stored in java class config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating instances on your own instead of letting spring inject it for you which is why you're losing all the dependencies like entitymanager, etc. change your DataFromUserController

```
@Controller
public class DataFromUserController {

@Autowired
private FilmDAO filmDao;

@Autowired
private DirectorDAO directorDao;

.....
}
```

Comment: When I tried Jayesh code I see stacktrace like below:

https://pastebin.com/dei2nx7f

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. This is present code of controller https://pastebin.com/AU4XRn3C

Comment: line 40 and 41, you need to use the autowired objects. `filmDao.insert(film);
        directorDao.insert(director)`