# NullPointer when I try to obtain list of objects

Tags: java, spring, entitymanager

In this question [NullPointer when call entity Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52029614/nullpointer-when-call-entity-manager/52029653#52029653) suggested to add `@Autowire` DAO into controller. I did it and it is working fine. Then I added the `@Transactional` anntotation in `DaoImpl` and every operation insert/delete/update was available except `select` statement. When I call this method I see *NPE*. Can anyone help?

```
public List<Object[]> showAll() {
        return filmDao.getAllFilms();
    }
```

This is full code of Controller: https://pastebin.com/BNi5EH86
Select looks like:

```
public List<Object[]> getAllFilms() {
    List<Object[]> all;
    EntityManager manager = getEntityManager();

    return manager.createQuery("SELECT film.id, film.tytul, film.czasTrwania, film.rozmiar, director.imieInazwisko FROM FilmDs film " +
            "JOIN DirectorDs director ON film.tytul=director.tytul").getResultList();
}
```

Print on the screen:

```
public void viewAll() {
        for (Object[] film : filmOperationController.showAll()) {
            Arrays.asList(film);
            System.out.print("Nr. " + film[0]
                    + ", Tytuł: " + film[1]
                    + ", Reżyser: " + film[4]
                    + ", Czas:  " + film[2]
                    + ", Wielkość pliku: " + film[3]
                    + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Full stacktrace :

> exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   Films.controller.FilmOperationController.showAll(FilmOperationController.java:50)
>   at Films.view.ViewFilm.viewAll(ViewFilm.java:16) at
>   Films.Main.showAndSearch(Main.java:40) at
>   Films.Main.main(Main.java:23)

Comment: In full code npe is on line 50. Yes, I tried and filmDao in this case is null.

Comment: Is it possible that one of the columns is null.

Comment: Please, show us the relevant code of `FilmDAO`...

Comment: Full code of programm on github

https://github.com/lukasz-chojn/films_database/tree/master/src/main/java/Films

Comment: Is filmDao a spring component then? So is has @Component,@Service,@Repository annotation over class definition? And is it component-scanned? Do you have this code on GitHub/gitlab, to show larger context?

Is it possible that one of the columns is null


Yes, every class has apriopriate anntotaion
Every column has data. Entity has NotNull

Comment: When asking for help in situations involving some exceptions, please make sure to post the full stack trace. It contains lots of information required to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Full stacktrace

xception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Films.controller.FilmOperationController.showAll(FilmOperationController.java:50)
 at Films.view.ViewFilm.viewAll(ViewFilm.java:16)
 at Films.Main.showAndSearch(Main.java:40)
 at Films.Main.main(Main.java:23)

Comment: Does this select statement return any results, if typed into SQL console? In older versions of hibernate no results could lead to returning null, instead of an empty list. But in hibernate 5 this should not be an issue.

Comment: Yes, this statement return 15 rows when I call it in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that your context doesn't contain `FilmDAO` bean. You can check it by adding `@Autowired(required=true)`.

It happens because you have 'interface + Impl' AND both Impl and interface are additionally marked as componets (`@Service` and `@Repository`).

You can fix it in the right way: just remove `FilmDAO` interface (and rename that ridiculous `FilmDAOImpl` to normal `FilmDAO`).

Comment: After removing annotation @Service  I see stacktrace like this:
https://pastebin.com/C5AkBScp

Comment: Because this is not the problem.

Comment: @ŁukaszChojnowski, try to remove that interface

Comment: @Beri do you have any suggestions how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have tried to run the app locally, but it's not working,secondly I don't have the schema to fully check. So I can't debug it correcrtly. My tip: Add logging inside of Dao, to see if you enter the FilmDaoImpl, if so, then check if enittyManager is notNUll, then if getResultList() returns null. So step by step find the NPE line.